# Error when importing numpy with a very simple script

Tags: python

I am receiving the following error when running a simple code which is the following:

```
import numpy as np

N = 10

diagonal = np.zeros(N) + 2

print diagonal
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "diagonalmatrix.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Users/jamesmalone/Documents/Python/Coursework/numpy.py", line 5, in <module>
    diagonal = np.zeros(N) + 2
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'zeros'
```

Comment: You have *named your own script `numpy`*, so that's what's getting `import`ed (and you don't define a `zeros`). **Don't do that**.

Comment: install numpy. you are getting this error because it is not present on yoru system.

Comment: @GaneshKamath no, if `numpy` wasn't installed the `import` would fail (`ImportError` not `AttributeError`).

Comment: Thank you, that was a problem. Once i deleted that file i recieved another error however:

File "diagonalmatrix.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
(and so on, was a much longer error)

I have installed numpy and scipy (twice now)

Comment: @malonej we can't guess the problem from the start of a long traceback. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide the appropriate information to diagnose the issue **in the question** (or, as you've already had an accurate answer to this question, open a new one for the new issue). Try reading and following http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ - you'll never get anywhere if you ask a new question at every small error.

Comment: thanks will do; coding noob over here. Cheers for the help on this one

Comment: @jonrsharpe what do you mean by you don't define a zeros? I got that idea from here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302923/how-to-create-a-diagonal-sparse-matrix-in-scipy

Comment: There is a `zeros` in the *actual `numpy` library*, but my point is that **that isn't what you imported**. Your own `numpy.py` file **does not** define a `zeros` attribute (if it did, you would have seen a different error).

Comment: Ahh i see what you mean now, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `numpy.py` file in your **current working directory**. You need to rename it with some other name and then try again. The thing is this file is getting imported rather than original `numpy` module.

Comment: You don't have to guess, you can see it in the traceback!